# python pandas datetime.time - datetime.time

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

i have a dataframe which contains two columns of datetime.time items. something like

```
   col1                 col2
02:10:00.008209    02:08:38.053145
02:10:00.567054    02:08:38.053145
02:10:00.609842    02:08:38.053145
02:10:00.728153    02:08:38.053145
02:10:02.394408    02:08:38.053145
```

how can i generate a col3 which is the differences between col1 and col2? (preferablly in microseconds)?

I searched around but I cannot find a solution here. Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

don't use `datetime.time`, use `timedelta`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
data = """col1                 col2
02:10:00.008209    02:08:38.053145
02:10:00.567054    02:08:38.053145
02:10:00.609842    02:08:38.053145
02:10:00.728153    02:08:38.053145
02:10:02.394408    02:08:38.053145"""
df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = df.apply(pd.to_timedelta)
diff = df2.col1 - df2.col2

diff.astype("i8")/1e9
```

the output is different in seconds:

```
0    81.955064
1    82.513909
2    82.556697
3    82.675008
4    84.341263
dtype: float64
```

To convert time dataframe to timedelta dataframe:

```
df.applymap(time.isoformat).apply(pd.to_timedelta)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want a DataFrame of `datetime.time` objects? There is hardly an operation you can perform conveniently on these guys especially when wrapped in a DataFrame.

It might be better to have each column store an int representing the total number of microseconds.

You can convert `df` to a DataFrame storing microseconds like this:

```
In [71]: df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: ((x.hour*60+x.minute)*60+x.second)*10**6+x.microsecond)

In [72]: df2
Out[72]: 
         col1        col2
0  7800008209  7718053145
1  7800567054  7718053145
```

And from there, it is easy to get the result you desire:

```
In [73]: df2['col1']-df2['col2']
Out[73]: 
0    81955064
1    82513909
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` converts `datetime` objects to `np.datetime64` objects, whose differences are `np.timedelta64` objects.

Consider this

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
                       0                          1
0 2014-02-28 13:30:19.926778 2014-02-28 13:30:47.178474
1 2014-02-28 13:30:29.814575 2014-02-28 13:30:51.183349
```

I can consider the column-wise difference by

```
 df[0] - df[1]


 Out[31]: 
 0   -00:00:27.251696
 1   -00:00:21.368774
 dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

and hence I can apply `timedelta64` conversions. For microseconds

```
(df[0] - df[1]).apply(lambda x : x.astype('timedelta64[us]')) #no actual difference when displayed
```

or microseconds as integers

```
(df[0] - df[1]).apply(lambda x : x.astype('timedelta64[us]').astype('int'))

 0   -27251696000
 1   -21368774000
 dtype: int64
```

**EDIT:** 
As suggessted by @Jeff, the last expressions can be shortened as

```
(df[0] - df[1]).astype('timedelta64[us]')
```

and

```
(df[0] - df[1]).astype('timedelta64[us]').astype('int')
```

for pandas >= .13.

Comment: in pandas >= 0.13, you can just do ``df[0]-df[1].astype('timedelta[us]')``